# What is the best way to store some data for anonymous user when using spring mvc with security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring security. I am building one shopping type application using spring boot and security.

I want to keep user anonymous until he reaches to checkout page, and every time he open the browser I want his browsing/shopping data to be available at the website.
Or if at any instance he chooses to login I want all his browsing/shopping information to be stored in database. Is there any alternate way available instead using cookies?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), i.e. `window.localStorage` to store the user's state directly in the browser using JavaScript. That storage persists if the user closes the browser and returns to your page at a later point of time.

You can even put complex JSON structures into the storage by converting them to/from string using the static methods of the [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object.

As soon as the user logs in to your shop you may implement a transfer of that data to your server application. This allows you to save the user's state in a server-side database.